# Create a View of type List in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am practicing MVC 2 (I'll do MVC 4 in just a bit) after almost 2 years, just to revise before I jump to MVC 4.

I am creating a strongly typed view of one of my data objects called **Category**. I want to create a list type view, i.e. a view that displays all records from the **Category** table.

I recall there used to be T4 templates of each type of view -- **Index**, **List**, **Create**, etc. that you could choose from.

But I can't find them. When I create the View, the **Add View** dialog shows a disabled input field for **View content**.

[image: Can't find the different types of Views to automatically generate]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have Visual Studio generate the list for you. After all, you need some lookup logic to get all the objects you want to display in the list.

You might want to check out [this blog post](http://www.iwantmymvc.com/populate-drop-down-list-mvc-3) for a nice way to pass a list of objects into your drop down list. You will, however, need to supply the objects yourself.